# parent qwidget in front of child

Tags: qt, operating-system

I have a program with several qwidget, each one is a separate window and each one are child of the same qmainwindow.

I want the parent window to be in front of the others if I click on it (like the usual behaviour on any os). It works on X11, but not on windows and OSX.

What should I do ?

By the way, on X11, all the different windows appear separately in the taskbar (which is not the case on windows).

Answer (score 0):

You should use [QMdiArea](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qmdiarea.html).
Example applications can be found f.i. [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/mainwindows-mdi.html) or [here](http://www.codeprogress.com/cpp/libraries/qt/qtClasses.php?item=QMdiArea).

Comment: The problem is that I think I won't be able to use multiple monitors with QMdiArea.

Comment: Why won't that be possible? I would say QMdiArea does show the usual behavior on any OS, as you require. Maybe I do not understand what you want exactly. However, you can allways subclass QMdiArea and tweak the behavior of the windows.